# How to update records of a database permanently?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, admin, dbeaver

I am using DBeaver to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database. I want to update all users' login count to zero.

I have tried running an `update` command as follow

`UPDATE app.dbo.users SET login_count = 0 WHERE 1`

When I ran a `select` on the users' table, it shows that the login count has been updated to 0. But when I disconnect from the database and viewed the records again, it has been reverted back to its original value.

How do I change it permanently using DBeaver? This might have something to do with 'view session'.

Comment: Is there someone else executing the update operation again? And are you sure the update SQL you write is right? It should be written like 'UPDATE app.dbo.users SET login_count = 0 WHERE login_count = 1' in usual.

Comment: I don't think so since I have stopped all services that are using the database. Yes the command is correct since it did reflect it before I disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

By default, SQL Server is set to auto-commit transactions.  However, it is possible for the database to be in manual commit mode (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/manual-commit-mode?view=sql-server-2017)).

If you run an `update` in a session *and* the update has not been committed, you will see the changes in the session.  But they will not be visible in any other sessions.

The solution is to run `commit` after the `update`.